# S-R label on cable

Tags: cable, case

I've got S-R label on a cable from front of my computer case.
Do you know what is it ?

Comment: What is the cable plugged into on each side?

Comment: is it a cable connecting the modem ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you asked about SR and SL, in that case I guess those wires are connected to your surround speakers. If that's true then

- SL Surround speaker (L)
- SR Surround speaker (R)

Comment: And what does it mean S-L in this case ?

Comment: In SR cables heat put changes according to temperature. SR cable increases heat output as temperature decreases and decreases heat output as temperature increases.

Comment: SL - sheathed  Lead cable

Comment: SR self regulating cable is for deicing gutters and other parts of your house. This cable actually generates heat for the purpose of melting snow. I doubt this is plugged into his computer. http://www.heatersplus.com/srtrace.htm

Comment: Why do I still have Down-votes :(

Answer (score 0):

SR Cables ("Short-range") are [networking cables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10GBASE-SR#10GBASE-SR), used for fiber optic communications.